# Issue while installing kivy using setup file

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, cython, lib

I was trying to install kivy using the setup file by using the following command

python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --root=/

but I am getting index error

`IndexError: tuple index out of range`

please find below the full error

```
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\Downloads\Kivy-2.2.1>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\cmm6mdv\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-12-04_3.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\Downloads\Kivy-2.2.1\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
Current directory is: C:\Users\cmm6mdv\Downloads\Kivy-2.2.1
Source and initial build directory is: C:\Users\cmm6mdv\Downloads\Kivy-2.2.1
Python path is:
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\Downloads\Kivy-2.2.1
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.zip
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\DLLs
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyodbc-5.0.1-py3.11-win-amd64.egg
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\wheel-0.42.0-py3.11.egg
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\Downloads\Kivy-2.2.1\kivy\modules
C:\Users\cmm6mdv\.kivy\mods


Found Cython at C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Cython\__init__.py
Detected supported Cython version 3.0.6

This version of Cython is untested with Kivy. While this version may
work perfectly fine, it is possible that you may experience issues.
Please downgrade to a supported version, or update cython_max in
setup.cfg to your version of Cython. It is best to use the newest
supported version, 0.29.33, but the minimum supported version is 0.24.

If your platform provides a Cython package, check if you can downgrade
to a supported version. Otherwise, uninstall the platform package and
install Cython via pip:

    pip install -I "cython>=0.24,<=0.29.33,!=0.27,!=0.27.2"

Please note that the following versions of Cython are not supported
at all: 0.27, 0.27.2

User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
Using this graphics system: OpenGL
WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

SDL2: missing sub library SDL
SDL2: missing sub library SDL_mixer
SDL2: missing sub library SDL_ttf
SDL2: missing sub library SDL_image
running build_ext
Building extensions in parallel using 2 cores
Build configuration is:
 * use_rpi_vidcore_lite = 0
 * use_egl = 0
 * use_opengl_es2 = 0
 * use_opengl_mock = 0
 * use_sdl2 = 0
 * use_pangoft2 = 0
 * use_ios = 0
 * use_android = 0
 * use_mesagl = 0
 * use_x11 = 0
 * use_wayland = 0
 * use_gstreamer = 0
 * use_avfoundation = 0
 * use_osx_frameworks = 0
 * debug_gl = 0
 * kivy_sdl_gl_alpha_size = 8
 * debug = False
Detected compiler is msvc
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\Downloads\Kivy-2.2.1\setup.py", line 1153, in <module>
     setup(
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
     return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
     return run_commands(dist)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
     dist.run_commands()
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
     self.run_command(cmd)
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
     super().run_command(command)
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
     cmd_obj.run()
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 84, in run
     _build_ext.run(self)
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 346, in run
     self.build_extensions()
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\Downloads\Kivy-2.2.1\setup.py", line 343, in build_extensions
     super().build_extensions()
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 464, in build_extensions
     self._build_extensions_parallel()
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 487, in _build_extensions_parallel
     fut.result()
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 456, in result
     return self.__get_result()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
     raise self._exception
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 246, in build_extension
     _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 130, in build_extension
     new_ext = cythonize(
               ^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1010, in cythonize
     module_list, module_metadata = create_extension_list(
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 886, in create_extension_list
     m, metadata = create_extension(template, kwds)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 766, in default_create_extension
     ext = t(**kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\cmm6mdv\Downloads\Kivy-2.2.1\setup.py", line 603, in __init__
     self.sources = args[1]
                    ~~~~^^^
 IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I am expecting the library to be installed and  I cannot use pip install

Comment: Would you say that the problem is that you are unable to unstall via `setup.py`, or that the problem is that you are unable to install? If it is the latter, you might find it easier to install via `pip` instead

Comment: the problem is that you are unable to unstall via setup.py and I may not be able to use pip due to some proxy issues

Answer (score 1):

You said you are trying to install Kivy with `python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --root=/` but in your logs the commands given was `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`.

According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html), the `...build_ext --inplace` is for recompilation in the event there is a change of Cython file; otherwise it was recommended to install through `pip` (if installing from source) using this command:

```
python -m pip install -e ".[dev,full]"
```

For a more comprehensive answer, `python -m pip install "kivy[base]" kivy_examples` command would suffice for installing minimum kivy build.

Comment: I cannot use pip due to some proxy issues

Comment: well, then download the wheel file from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/#files) and pip install locally, as per the [documentation here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#what-is-pip-and-what-are-wheels).  

The example in the documentation uses the command `python -m pip install C:\Kivy-1.9.1.dev-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` as an example. so give this a try